# Trying to do maths with vba but need to keep cells current formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create code and understand how I can keep the cells current formulas intact. I want to be able to create a new formula where if a cell had a formula such as (=E4+E5) if I add it with another cell again such as E5 it gives the output = E4+E5+E5. My current code gives me the output E4+E512 which I really don't understand why. I am currently replacing the "=" sign that comes with when taking a cell.formula  so that my output is not =E4+=E5+E5

current code:

```
Public Sub blokkie_toets()
Dim cell_for As Range
Dim cell_new As Range

Set cell_for = Range("E7")
Set cell_new = Range("E4")

If Left(cell_for.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
      ActiveCell = Replace(cell_for.Formula, "=", "") + cell_new.Formula
End If



End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `ActiveCell.Formula = Replace(cell_for.Formula, "=", "") & cell_new.Formula`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns unfortunately it returns the same value I get in E9

Comment: Does E4 have a formula?  Looks like it's just a constant value of 12

Comment: @TimWilliams It does not but I need to be able to just add that number to the other formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a reference to E4 then you need to use `Address()`

```vba
Dim cell_for As Range
Dim cell_new As Range

Set cell_for = Range("E7")
Set cell_new = Range("E4")

cell_for.Formula = cell_for.Formula & "+" & cell_new.Address(False, False)
```